# Can I get pictures/stills/photos from inside a container file from a CD-I disc?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, containers, extract

I have `ffmpeg` setup.

Is there a way to extract `pictures/stills/photos` (etc) from a container (file) that's from an old CD-I game that I have.

I don't want to extract the audio nor video. And I don't want frames from the videos either.

I want the bitmaps (etc) from INSIDE that container file.

I know my Windows 8.1 PC can't read inside that container file - so I'm hoping there's a way to extract all the files (I want) instead using `ffmpeg`.

(IsoBuster only gives the audio and video so I know already about IsoBuster.)

I think there are no individual headers for the `pictures/stills/photos`, etc.

Here's what ExifTool decoded the file as:

```
ExifTool Version Number (10.68) 
File Name (green.3t) 
File Size (610 MB) 
File Permissions (rw-rw-rw-) 
File Type (MPEG) 
File Type Extension (mpg) 
MIME Type (video/mpeg) 
MPEG Audio Version (1) 
Audio Layer (2) 
Audio Bitrate (80 kbps) 
Sample Rate (44100) 
Channel Mode (Single Channel) 
Mode Extension (Bands 4-31)
Copyright Flag (False) 
Original Media (False) 
Emphasis (None) 
Image Width (368)
Image Height (272) 
Aspect Ratio (1.0695) 
Frame Rate (25 fps) 
Video Bitrate (1.29 Mbps) 
Duration (1:02:12 approx) 
Image Size (368x272) 
Megapixels (0.100)
```

Thank you for reading and - help!! :D

Comment: Why do you think there are no headers? Why do you think `exiftool` can read the file? Have you tried running the Linux `strings` command on the file to see if there is anything resembling a filename string? Have you tried dumping the first few lines in hex?

Comment: Hello, Mark. I think there are no headers because I read this: "Unfortunately, that doesn't work because the pictures are wrapped into huge files and - what kills any chance - all "headers" of the image data are missing" (http://cdii.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/how-to-convert-cd-i-image-files.html). Sorry, I forgot to add that. I used exiftool to highlight something about the file (because I'm a beginner using ffmpeg and exiftool). I don't know how to run Linux strings so would you tell me? And explain about dumping hex? (I know about HxD.)